# Mongoose findOne() returns an empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am finding one single document using `findOne()`
My document has `userid` as one of the key inside my users model.

**Example**

```
{
   userid: 1,
   name: 'John'
}
```

Now I am able to receive this document as object when I do the following

```
users.findOne({userid: 1}, function(e, data){
   if(e){
      return (res.send('Failed'))
   }else{
      return (res.send(data))
   }
});
```

**However**, if I try to submit the same value of `userid` dynamically then the `data` obj returns `null` and still `if(e)` statement is not executed.

**Example**

```
users.findOne({userid: req.body.userid}, function(e, data){
   if(e){
      return (res.send('Failed'))
   }else{
      return (res.send(data))
   }
});
```

I console logged the value of `req.body.userid` and checked that it is 1 when I pass it dynamically.

What am I doing wrong? Is the value of `req.body.userid` not passed correctly to `userid` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to pass filter values using variables you need to set it correctly using a filter object

Check the code below

```
var key = "userId"; //example
var value = req.body.userId;
var filter = {};
filter[key] = value;

    user.model.findOne(filter, function(e, data){
       if(e){
          return (res.send('Failed'))
       }else{
          return (res.send(data))
       }
    });
```

Comment: Now if(e) executed and the error says i have a cast error."name": "CastError", Also, i have made sure that the value of req.body.userid is integer.

Comment: console.log the value of  `req.body.userid`, `typeof req.body.userid` and `parseInt(req.body.userid)`  to be able to see what is coming from the request and the type of `userid`  ... because the error means that the `parseInt` function result is `NAN` which means the `req.body.userid` is not a number string or even a number

Comment: The exptected type of userid in the document is number and the typeOf req.body.userid is also a number.

Comment: But how `parseInt` return `NAN` if its a number ? ...i can't see any possible error in your code other than that .... maybe the value you are logging is different from the one you pass to `findOne` filter ? maybe you have a typo ?   as if its  a number it should `parseInt` correctly

Comment: userid is a demo that I used as an example. I am passing key as the actual value. So my final code looks like this findOne({ key: key }, function....) Is it reserved by mongodb or mongoose or perhaps express?

Comment: Probably your variables are not passed correctly to filter ... i updated the answer ... i think this should work for you ... just add the correct values in filter object based on your real code